# Change Time Field for specific Rows in mySQL DB

Tags: mysql

Anyone have any suggestions for an SQL statement that will change a time field for a filtered set of rows?

I have about 1500 rows that have a time column. I need to subtract 4 minutes from every row that has a certain user id...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is a `TIME` type then the [`ADDTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function will work. Just use a negative 'hour:minute':

```
ADDTIME(my_column, '-0:04')
```

Comment: Ok, let me see if I have this right in my head. Use an UPDATE statement that applies the ADDTIME to all my SELECTED rows...correct?

Comment: If I understand correctly and this is a `TIME` or `DATETIME` column, then yes: `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = ADDTIME(my_column, '-0:04') WHERE ...`. If it's a `TIMESTAMP` column the answer will be different.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is a TIME type column. Thanks Ed!